# Complex Subquery in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, subquery

I have to show result like this:

```
Sr.No. |  Subject Code  | Name of Subject | Marks obtained Lowest | Marks obtained Highest | No. of students Appeared | No of Students Passed | Percent of Pass | Percent of above 60% students|
```

for more than 4 subjects

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Summery_TestMarks]
(
        @courseId int,@SchemeID int, @AcadYear nvarchar(15), @Semest nvarchar(15)
)
AS
        select SM.Subj_Code, SM.Subj_Name, Min(TM1.Test1_Marks) as Lowest, MAX(TM1.Test1_Marks) as Highest, count(TM1.Stud_ID) as appeared, 
        (select Count(TM1.STUD_ID) from Test1_Marks TM1 
        inner join SUBJECT_MASTER SM on TM1.Subj_ID = SM.Subject_ID
        where TM1.Test1_Marks> 9
        AND TM1.Course_ID = @courseId AND TM1.Scheme_ID = @SchemeID AND TM1.Semester = @Semest AND TM1.Acad_Year = @AcadYear 
        )as Passed, 

        (select Count(TM1.STUD_ID) from Test1_Marks TM1 
        inner join SUBJECT_MASTER SM on TM1.Subj_ID = SM.Subject_ID
        where  TM1.Test1_Marks> 9 
        AND TM1.Course_ID = @courseId AND TM1.Scheme_ID = @SchemeID AND TM1.Semester = @Semest AND TM1.Acad_Year = @AcadYear  )*100/ (count(TM1.Stud_ID))  
        as percentage,

        ((select count(TM1.STUD_ID) as above60 from Test1_Marks TM1 where (TM1.Test1_Marks*100/25) > 60 )*100/
        (select count(TM1.STUD_ID) from Test1_Marks TM1)) as above60 from Test1_Marks TM1 

        inner join SUBJECT_MASTER SM on TM1.Subj_ID = SM.Subject_ID
        where TM1.Course_ID = @courseId AND TM1.Scheme_ID = @SchemeID AND TM1.Semester = @Semest AND TM1.Acad_Year = @AcadYear 
        group by SM.Subj_Name, SM.Subj_Code
```

I'm getting errors with this. How can I solve this? 
I have tried a lot but it's giving problems.

Comment: I highly recommend you give some detail about what your errors are.

Comment: *but getting errors*, can you be a little (and by that I mean "a lot") more specific about that?. What is the error message (or messages)?, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: How can you solve this?  Comment out all your code and replace it with "select courseID, AcadYear, Semest".  Then start adding parts bit by bit.  Test early, test often and when in doubt, test.  By the way, I couldn't put the @ symbols in the sample query because SO barked at me.

Comment: @Adam Miller - when I run this query it gives correct result till Sr.No. |  Subject Code  | Name of Subject | Marks obtained Lowest | Marks obtained Highest | No. of students Appeared But for 'No of Students Passed' it counts total students of all subjects... no.of sutudents * no of subjects. and gives percentage of all subjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this greatly by putting a `CASE ... END` inside a `SUM()`. This is an abbreviated version of your query just to demonstrate the basic concept:

```
SELECT tm.CourseID, MIN(Test1_Marks) [LowestScore], MAX(Test1_Marks) [HighestScore], COUNT(Stud_ID) [NumberOfStudents]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Test1_Marks > 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [NumberWhoPassed]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Test1_Marks > 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(Stud_ID) [PercentWhoPassed]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN TM1.Test1_Marks*100/25) > 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(Stud_ID) [PercentAbove60]
FROM Test_Marks tm
GROUP BY tm.CourseID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  SM.Subj_Code, 
            SM.Subj_Name, 
            MIN(TM1.Test1_Marks) AS Lowest, 
            MAX(TM1.Test1_Marks) AS Highest, 
            COUNT(TM1.Stud_ID) AS Appeared, 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN TM1.Test1_Marks > 9 THEN TM1.STUD_ID END) AS Passed,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN TM1.Test1_Marks*100/25) > 60 THEN TM1.STUD_ID END) * 100 /
            COUNT(TM1.Stud_ID) AS Above60
    FROM Test1_Marks TM1 
    INNER JOIN SUBJECT_MASTER SM 
        ON TM1.Subj_ID = SM.Subject_ID
    WHERE TM1.Course_ID = @courseId 
    AND TM1.Scheme_ID = @SchemeID 
    AND TM1.Semester = @Semest 
    AND TM1.Acad_Year = @AcadYear 
    GROUP BY SM.Subj_Name, SM.Subj_Code
)
SELECT  Subj_Code, 
        Subj_Name, 
        Lowest, 
        Highest, 
        Appeared, 
        Passed,
        Passed*100.0/Appeared AS Percentage
        Above60
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely as a troubleshooting tactic in a case like this, one thing you could do, if you haven't, is to pull out all those little subselects and run them individually against your database to make sure they give meaningful results and no errors.

Comment: Thanks to all above who support...

Answer (score 0):

I got result as helped by @Joel Coehoorn -

```
select TM.Subj_ID, SM.Subj_Name ,MIN(TM.Test1_Marks) [LowestScore], MAX(TM.Test1_Marks)[HighestScore], COUNT(TM.STUD_ID) [NumberOfStudents],
SUM(CASE WHEN TM.Test1_Marks > 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)[NumberWhoPassed],
SUM(CASE WHEN TM.Test1_Marks > 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*100 / count(TM.STUD_ID) [PercentWhoPassed],
SUM(CASE WHEN (TM.Test1_Marks * 100 / 25)>60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*100/ count(TM.STUD_ID) [PercentAbove60]
 from Test1_Marks TM
 join SUBJECT_MASTER SM on TM.Subj_ID = SM.Subject_ID
 WHERE TM.Course_ID = 1 AND TM.Scheme_ID = 2 AND TM.Semester = '3rd Semester' AND TM.Acad_Year = '2013-2014' 
 GROUP BY TM.Subj_ID, SM.Subj_Name
```

Thanks to all participants for showing interest ... @Adam Miller, @Lamak, @Dan Bracuk, @Joel Coehoorn